# Cannot display MAF ui object in my host

Tags: c#, wpf, add-in, maf

I have Implemented the MAF Framework, creating a pipeline and an AddIn which sends a

```
<!-- language-all: lang-cc -->
```

`UserControl` to my host which is a plugin itself.

The control to be sent to the host is written as below, it implements `UserControl` and contains an additional string property:

```
Contract : public interface ITestSuiteUiContract : INativeHandleContract  
AddInViews : public class TestSuiteUi : UserControl
HostViews :  public abstract class AbstractTestSuiteUi : UserControl
```

The host loads the AddIn and the requested UI. I can call methods, but I can't display my `AddIn` UI object into my host container:

```
ViewModel: TestSuiteUiContainer = _TestSuiteLoader.LoadedTestSuite.GetTestSuiteWpfUiObjects()[0];`  
View : `<ContentControl Content="{Binding TestSuiteUiContainer}"/>
```

unless I put it in a separate window 
`new Window { Content = TestSuiteUicontainer }.Show();`

or even if I put the hole plugin view in a separate window.

My plugin is displaying all `UserControl` Objects exept my AddIn ui object.

Here's my Hostside TestSuiteUi contract to

view adapter :

```
public TestSuiteUiContractToViewAdapter(TestSuiteUiContract contract)
{
    _contract = contract;
    _handle = new ContractHandle(_contract);
    string aqn = typeof(INativeHandleContract).AssemblyQualifiedName;
    INativeHandleContract inhc = (INativeHandleContract)SourceContract.QueryContract(aqn);
    FrameworkElement fe = (FrameworkElement)FrameworkElementAdapters.ContractToViewAdapter(inhc);
    this.Content = fe;
}
```

And here's the list returned by my AddIn:

```
public List<AbstractTestSuiteUi> GetTestSuiteWpfUiObjects()
{
    var list = new List<AbstractTestSuiteUi>();
    for (int i = 0; i < SourceContract.GetTestSuiteWpfUiObjects().GetCount(); i++)
    {
        list.Add(Adapt.ToView<ITestSuiteUiContract, AbstractTestSuiteUi, TestSuiteUiContractToViewAdapter>(SourceContract.GetTestSuiteWpfUiObjects().GetItem(i)));
    }
    return list;
}
```

Here are methods added to my

```
TestSuiteUiViewTocontractAdapter:
    public override IContract QueryContract(string contractIdentifier)
    {
        if (contractIdentifier.Equals(typeof(INativeHandleContract).AssemblyQualifiedName))
        {
            return FrameworkElementAdapters.ViewToContractAdapter(this.SourceView);
        }
        return base.QueryContract(contractIdentifier);
    }

    [SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode)]
    public IntPtr GetHandle()
    {
        return FrameworkElementAdapters.ViewToContractAdapter(this.SourceView).GetHandle();
    }
```

Comment: Using snoop, the Content property of the ContentControl shows HostSideAdapters.ContractToViewAdapters.DataTypes.TestSuiteUiContractToViewAdapter{Path=TestSuiteUiContainer}. so it gets the object right but can't display it.

Comment: Even when reimplementing the msdn example here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb909887(v=vs.100).aspx
I still get the same issue :
`MainView.DockPanelContainer.Children.Add(_testSuiteLoader.LoadedTestSuite.GetAddInUI());`
`new Window() { Content = _testSuiteLoader.LoadedTestSuite.GetAddInUI() }.Show();  
where first line fails to display and the second one displays my ui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone faces the same issue, here's the answer found in msdn forum :
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cd30e928-31c8-4352-b86a-c6bcd64a3192/addin-apperence-issuein-wpf?forum=wpf

Comment: You can find further information under WPF Addin limitations section
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb909794(v=VS.110).aspx